# 500 error with all headers

Tags: c#, ssis, webclient

I am just trying to ping google or some site to see if I can get this code working.  I am new to C#, so I have no idea why this is wrong.  Is there anything I am missing?

```
 System.Net.WebClient myWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();

 myWebClient.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("--mywebproxy--");

 myWebClient.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2.6) Gecko/20100625 Firefox/3.6.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"; 
 myWebClient.Headers["Accept"] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"; 
 myWebClient.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-us,en;q=0.5"; 
 myWebClient.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "    gzip,deflate"; 
 myWebClient.Headers["Accept-Charset"] = "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"; 

 myWebClient.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;


 myWebClient.DownloadData("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Wrap the code around at Try{}Catch{} and report back whee you are actually getting the error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you're using an actual URI

like,

```
System.Net.WebClient myWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient { Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("http://127.0.0.1") };
```

If it still doesn't work, intall IIS and try again.

You're whole code would be

```
        var myWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient { Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("http://127.0.0.1") };


        myWebClient.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2.6) Gecko/20100625 Firefox/3.6.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)";
        myWebClient.Headers["Accept"] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        myWebClient.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-us,en;q=0.5";
        myWebClient.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "    gzip,deflate";
        myWebClient.Headers["Accept-Charset"] = "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";

        myWebClient.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;


        var x = myWebClient.DownloadData("http://www.google.com");
```